# How to open Map activity and set location from another activity?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, gps

I am new to Android Programming and I am trying to create an application using Android Studio.

I have a list view which contains several items. Once an item is clicked, it shows an alert dialog containing the details of the clicked item. All of these are working perfectly fine. The problem is, there is a button on the alert dialog which should lead to the map activity I created pointing the exact location as given from the activity that calls it. It calls and opens the map activity but does not put the focus to the location of the item clicked. Instead it goes to the default marker i set if GPS is not enabled and to the location of the user if GPS in enabled.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I tried these lines of codes but instead of opening the map activity I made, it opens the Google Maps application:

```
Uri newIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:13.621085324664428, 123.21271363645793?z=20");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newIntentUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you provide some code that shows the issue? please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TimPenner I updated my post. I added some lines I found somewhere. But it opens the Google Maps application instead. It sets the focus to where I want it to, but I want to show it in the map activity within the app I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found this code somewhere and now it's working fine.

I added this set of codes on the other activity that calls the map with the coordinates: (in my case, I named it as schoolsList.java and my map nagaCityMapping.java)

```
double newLat = 13.621085324664428;
double newLong = 123.21271363645793;

LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(newLat,newLong);

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("longLat_dataProvider", fromPosition);

Intent i = new Intent(schoolsList.this, nagaCityMapping.class);
i.putExtras(args);
startActivity(i);
```

and then I received the intent to my map activity like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
LatLng ll = i.getParcelableExtra("longLat_dataProvider");

if (i != null && ll != null)
{
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(ll.latitude, ll.longitude), 20));

    LatLng defaultLoc = new LatLng(ll.latitude, ll.longitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(defaultLoc));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW), the ACTION_VIEW intent will perform the action you are seeing:

> public static final String ACTION_VIEW
>
> Added in API level 1
> Activity Action: Display the data to the user. This is the most common action performed on data -- it is the generic action you can use on a piece of data to get the most reasonable thing to occur. For example, when used on a contacts entry it will view the entry; when used on a mailto: URI it will bring up a compose window filled with the information supplied by the URI; when used with a tel: URI it will invoke the dialer.

Please see the Android tutorial on [adding maps to your application](https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html) or [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_6_connect_an_android_device):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The basics are [explained here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_a_fragment)

Comment: I already have a map activity and it is working, what I was actually asking is how can I call this map (the map I made on my application) from another activity and set the focus to where I wanted.

Comment: I got it. I posted my answer that I finally got working. Thanks anyway.